# C#: How to close quickly a WebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, request, httpwebrequest, webrequest

i'm having a problem with webrequest. I'm trying to parse a great amount of HTML documents, and sometimes i receive only the  part. The problem persist until i close the application and open it again. So i guess it's a defense mechanism against too many requests in the server side.

I tried to create a new WebRequest object every time i parse a HTML document, but the problem persists, and only sometimes it stop happen after a variable amount of seconds.

I think this could happen because the connection remains open until the garbage collector completely destroy the object. There's some way to immediately restart the connection? Thank you.

Comment: Show some code, it's hard to tell what you may be doing wrong if we can't see what you're currently doing.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do WebClient might be a better choice (quite easy to manage lifecycle), but as Matthew mentioned it's hard to know without code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask